# How to fix run time 1004: No cells were found error

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

The code below (finding the last row) had been working fine before, but it started making the

> run time error 1004

(3rd line). I've read similar post here, but would like to fix it on this specific code.

```
With Sheet1.Range("A:A")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        ' next line is where it errors
        Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
        Set rng = rng.Areas(rng.Areas.Count)
        lastrow = rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count).Row
    End If

End With
```

Comment: It is like that, probably because You don't have any `Constants` in Column A. Put there any values or use Error Handling - `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: This is code I have [given](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58751050/9758194) you. It would be decent to mention this, and even more decent to recognize the anwer I provided (questions I asked about this error)  before opening a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's no way to trap the error in `.specialcells` method.

Following workaround can be used.

```
With Sheet1.Range("A:A")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        ' next line is where it errors
        On Error Resume Next 'Avoid Error Call
        Set Rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
        On Error GoTo 0 'Reset Error Ignoring Behavior
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Set Rng = Rng.Areas(Rng.Areas.Count)
            lastrow = Rng.Cells(Rng.Cells.Count).Row
        End If
    End If
End With
```